# UIPickerView choices shown on label

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My UIPickerView has 3 components and there are three labels underneath. When an answer is chosen for 1 component of the picker I'd like the first label to show that components answer. Then the second and third component be shown on the 2nd and 3rd label. However it is currently not working as I thought, any suggestions?

I'm thinking my issue lies in the "-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:" section

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource,  UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker1;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label3;

@end
```

and:

```
import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()
{
NSArray*othercolourArray;
NSArray*otherseasonArray;
NSArray*otherotherArray;
}


@end


@implementation ViewController2



- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

othercolourArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Health Prof", @"Housekeep",     @"Visitors", @"Other",nil];
otherseasonArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Midwife", @"Nurse", @"Doctor",@"Other", nil];
otherotherArray =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Known Midwife", @"New Midwife", @"Doctor",@"Other", nil];


}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 3;


}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return othercolourArray.count;
        break;


    case 1:
        return otherseasonArray.count;
        break;

    case 2:
        return otherotherArray.count;
        break;



    default:
        break;
}


return 0;
}



-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

// This method provides the data for a specific row in a specific component.

switch (component) {
    case 0:
        return [othercolourArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;


    case 1:
        return [otherseasonArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;


    case 2:
        return [otherotherArray objectAtIndex:row];
        break;





    default:
        break;
}


return 0;



}


-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:    (NSInteger)component
{
_label1.text = [othercolourArray objectAtIndex: row];
_label2.text = [otherseasonArray objectAtIndex: row ];
_label3.text = [otherotherArray objectAtIndex: row ];

}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: `However it is currently not working as I thought, any suggestions?` please elaborate or give us an error log or something :(

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent` needs a bit more logic added I think. At the moment it looks like it'll switch the text for all labels depending on the last component-row combination. From reading your description, it looks like you need to set the label based on the row selected in a specific component. Maybe the below is what you're after.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    switch (component) {
        case 0:
            _label1.text = [othercolourArray objectAtIndex: row];
            break;
        case 1:
            _label2.text = [otherseasonArray objectAtIndex: row];
            break;
        case 2:
            _label3.text = [otherotherArray objectAtIndex: row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, just needed to replace:

```
_label1.text = [othercolourArray objectAtIndex: row];
```

with

```
_label1.text = [othercolourArray objectAtIndex: [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

and so on with the other components, thanks anyways !